# How do I join a table and display a column based on the newest date and a condition in two other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join two tables on their customerID. I have a table of customer information and a table of purchase information. In the joined table, I want a column to display the most recent purchase information for that customer. However, some customers have not yet made a purchase...I want that field for them to remain blank or null. Additionally, I only want to show Type A purchases, not Type B purchases.

I found a solution for displaying the latest record, but I can't get it to display null if they customer doesn't have a record (it just removes that customer from the join table completely instead of leaving a null field...regardless of join type):

```
SELECT c.*, p1.*
FROM customer c
JOIN purchase p1 ON (c.id = p1.customer_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase p2 ON (c.id = p2.customer_id AND 
    (p1.date < p2.date OR p1.date = p2.date AND p1.id < p2.id))
WHERE p2.id IS NULL and p2.purchase_Type = 'A';
```

Lets say my fields are:
customerTable: customer_ID, customer_Name
purchaseTable: customer_ID, purchase_Type (A or B), purchase_Price, purchase_Notes.

I want my join table to display:
customer_ID, Customer_Name, purchase_Price (most recent), purchase_Notes (most recent)

for every customer in my customer table, even if they haven't made a purchase, and I only want the purchasePrice and purchaseNotes to display for Type A purchases, otherwise the field is left null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions or `apply`.  The latter:

```
SELECT c.*, p.*
FROM customer c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) p.*
      FROM purchase p 
      WHERE p.customer_id = c.id and p.type = 'A'
      ORDER BY date DESC
     ) p;
```